# swift cannot convert value of type 'Plugin.Type' to expected argument type 'MyClass?'

Tags: swift, flutter

I'm using my own framework in my flutter plugin,

```
public class Plugin: NSObject, ISDKDelegate, FlutterPlugin, ISTokenUpdateDelegate, ISEventEngine2Delegate {

  public static func register(with registrar: FlutterPluginRegistrar) {
    let channel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "MySDK", binaryMessenger: registrar.messenger())
    let instance = Plugin()

    let decoder = ISDecoder.shared()
    decoder?.add(self)
```

And the error is

```
error: cannot convert value of type 'Plugin.Type' to expected argument type 'ISDKDelegate?'
        decoder?.add(self)
```

This code works well when I use it in AppDelegate.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code works well when I use it in AppDelegate. What am I doing wrong?

You made the function `static` so `self` is now the class. Change `self` to `instance`.